# Hosted KMZ not accessible in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, windows-server-2008, dreamweaver, kml, kmz

I made a web map for our local community garden with the plot numbers on it, which operates correctly from my github page:
http://jcguarneri.github.io/accugardens.html

However, when I delivered the html document and data files to the community garden to host on their website, the KMZ garden plot data I use will not draw:
http://tryufm.org/communitygarden/virtual%20map/gardenmap.html

The person administering the website and server there assure me that they are all in the same directory and that none of the filenames were changed. To further assess the situation, I tried accessing the KMZ file and the marker image file from my browser. The image (mobileimgs2.png) works from both sites. I am able to download the KMZ (PlotsLabels.kmz) from the github page, but not from the community garden page. The garden page returns the error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." Similarly, if I add the url to the KMZ as a layer in Google Earth, I can see the one from github but the one from the garden webpage cannot connect.

I don't have access to their server, so I only have limited information. I was able to find out that they are using Dreamweaver and hosting their page with Windows Server 2008. Any information I can get to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the server set up correctly to serve KMZ files? Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my KML feed working with Google Maps anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237997/why-isnt-my-kml-feed-working-with-google-maps-anymore)

Comment: That does seem like the most logical solution. I've relayed the instructions at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx to the server admin, but it didn't seem to work. Again, not being the admin, I don't know for sure if it was done correctly.

Comment: One test might be to upload a KML file and serve it as XML (with the .xml extending), if that works, but these shame file with a .kml extension doesn't, then the server is not set up correctly for KML. Unfortunately, doesn't say anything about KMZ.